# How to adjust query's using forms

Tags: php, mysql

(PHP and MySQL)

I need to adjust a mySQL query using a HTML form. I'm able to display the SELECT * version of the database to my webpage, but I need to be able to search for things like between dates and names. What is the best way to do this?

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
if ($date1 && $date2){
    $ab = "WHERE matchDate BETWEEN " . $date1 . "AND " . $date2;
}
else {
    $ab = " ";
}



$mySQL_command = "SELECT * FROM matches " . $ab . " ORDER BY matchDate DESC LIMIT 250;";
```

Which works to display everything when I'm not altering the query but when I go to submit my between dates the whole thing just dies without an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your dates are **proper MySQL dates**. Also, you need to change your code a bit and wrap the dates:

```
if ($date1 && $date2){
    $ab = "WHERE matchDate BETWEEN '" . $date1 . "' AND '" . $date2 . "'";
} else {
    $ab = "";
}
```

Comment: It appears wrapping the input was the key. Got it to work for a few other conditionals besides the date. I can't seem to get it to work on a WHERE...LIKE though, despite my exact command working in puTTY.

Comment: First of all, glad to hear it works; you can mark the answer as helpful if that's the case. Second, if you elaborate on your other issue I will be happy to take a look at it.